# Content Slider in JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, overlay

Essentially, what I'm trying to accomplish is making a content slider that has opaque yellow divs that slide over transitioning images (up state) then slide down to about 100px over the bottom of the images in a gray color (down state). These down states should act as slide selectors that when clicked expand to the up state and related image.

I've tried using several content and slideshow builds to make this happen but none of them really allow me to develop the effect. s3Slider is the one I've had most success with as it gets the up state animations per slide.

Here's the js::

```
(function($){  

$.fn.s3Slider = function(vars) {       

    var element     = this;
    var timeOut     = (vars.timeOut != undefined) ? vars.timeOut : 4000;
    var current     = null;
    var timeOutFn   = null;
    var faderStat   = true;
    var mOver       = false;
    var items       = $("#" + element[0].id + "Content ." + element[0].id + "Image");
    var itemsSpan   = $("#" + element[0].id + "Content ." + element[0].id + "Image span");

    items.each(function(i) {

        $(items[i]).mouseover(function() {
           mOver = true;
        });

        $(items[i]).mouseout(function() {
            mOver   = false;
            fadeElement(true);
        });

    });

    var fadeElement = function(isMouseOut) {
        var thisTimeOut = (isMouseOut) ? (timeOut/2) : timeOut;
        thisTimeOut = (faderStat) ? 10 : thisTimeOut;
        if(items.length > 0) {
            timeOutFn = setTimeout(makeSlider, thisTimeOut);
        } else {
            console.log("Poof..");
        }
    }

    var makeSlider = function() {
        current = (current != null) ? current : items[(items.length-1)];
        var currNo      = jQuery.inArray(current, items) + 1
        currNo = (currNo == items.length) ? 0 : (currNo - 1);
        var newMargin   = $(element).width() * currNo;
        if(faderStat == true) {
            if(!mOver) {
                $(items[currNo]).fadeIn((timeOut/6), function() {
                    if($(itemsSpan[currNo]).css('bottom') == 0) {
                        $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideUp((timeOut/6), function() {
                            faderStat = false;
                            current = items[currNo];
                            if(!mOver) {
                                fadeElement(false);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideDown((timeOut/6), function() {
                            faderStat = false;
                            current = items[currNo];
                            if(!mOver) {
                                fadeElement(false);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            if(!mOver) {
                if($(itemsSpan[currNo]).css('bottom') == 0) {
                    $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideDown((timeOut/6), function() {
                        $(items[currNo]).fadeOut((timeOut/6), function() {
                            faderStat = true;
                            current = items[(currNo+1)];
                            if(!mOver) {
                                fadeElement(false);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    $(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideUp((timeOut/6), function() {
                    $(items[currNo]).fadeOut((timeOut/6), function() {
                            faderStat = true;
                            current = items[(currNo+1)];
                            if(!mOver) {
                                fadeElement(false);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    makeSlider();

};  

})(jQuery);
```

It's a pretty short code and I'm trying to modify it to get the effect I want. It looks like the code calls for the .slideUp and .slideDown events from jquery. I can't figure out how to make those animations not hide the content but to animate to the aforementioned down state height.

Any help on that specifically would be great. Any help on the whole content slider solution would be a life saver!

Thanks for your time and assistance in helping me understand the world of jquery.

Comment: [link](http://www.bwpcommunications.com/testpage/index.php) here's the current page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the animate function instead of slideUp, like this...

```
$someDiv.animate({top: '-=200'});
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Thanks for the response! But, I'm getting syntaxt errors when I replace slideDown and slideUp with .animate. Tips?

Comment: Okay, solved for syntax errors. Now, I've replaced .slideUp/Down with .animate and now the divs aren't appearing... I did a simple version animating +=200 and -=200. Kept the rest of the code intact. Thoughts?

Comment: do they not appear at all? or only during or after the animation? take off the animate and see if they show up in the right starting pos. could be a css issue. for proof of concept, get a simple version to work on JSFiddle before concluding the problem is with the .animate().